# Neovim Lua integration

Tags: neovim, plugin-system, vimscript-lua

I'm trying to understand how can I use Lua to extend Neovim, following a baby steps approach. Something like:

```lua
-- ~/.config/nvim/lua/test.lua

local api = vim.api
local firstmodule = {}

function firstmodule.hello_world()
  api.nvim_command('echo "hello world"')
end

return firstmodule
```

Then in my **init.vim** I import the module to a command:

```
command! Greet lua require 'test'.hello_world()
```

And I get a command `:Greet` that prints **hello world**.

---

So far so good, but how can I get/use a string returned by a **lua function**, let's say:

```lua
function firstmodule.hello_string()
  return 'hello world'
end
```

I try to call this function in my `init.vim`:

```
let g:Myvar = v:lua.test.hello_string()
```

When I source the file, I get the errors:

```
E121: Undefined variable: v:lua
E15: Invalid expression: v:lua.test.hello_string()
```

How can I use that string returned by a lua function, let's say in my statusline?

Comment: You're getting `E121: Undefined variable: v:lua`... Are you sure you're using NeoVim and not Vim? It seems `v:lua` is a NeoVim specific interface not present in Vim...

Comment: Please don't post answers in questions. If an answer solved your problem, mark it accepted (as you did). If you have an answer to share, add it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't familiar with the procedure. Will do.

Comment: Hmm, so I can accept an answer, and add another one myself(not the accepted one), just to clarify and do a bit of cleanup?

Comment: IMO, if you're clarifying something the better approach is to edit the answer...IF you have the rep to do so. If you don't then asking the answer's author in a comment to add that information is probably a good choice. A new answer should be reserved for a different approach altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v:lua` interface was only introduced to NeoVim in [PR #11338](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/11338), which has a milestone of 0.5, so it looks like it's not generally available in released versions of NeoVim just yet. (NeoVim 0.5 is still in Beta as of early May 2020.)

You should use the [`luaeval()`](https://vimhelp.org/if_lua.txt.html#lua-luaeval) Vimscript function to evaluate a Lua expression (such as a function call) and use the returned value back in Vimscript.

In your case, it seems to me this should work:

```
let g:Myvar = luaeval('require("test").hello_string()')
```

---

Inside `'statusline'`, you can use `%{...}` to evaluate a Vim expression, which could be a global variable such as `g:Myvar` or even a `luaeval(...)` function call. Just keep in mind that `'statusline'` is evaluated quite often, so the overhead of using a Lua function call from there might become quite noticeable and produce lag while editing.

A solution that uses some caching should be used to avoid that, either a Vim global variable updated from an autocmd (such as CursorHold, CursorMoved, CursorMovedI, SafeState, etc.) or a Vim function that evaluates whether conditions changed and require a new call to the Lua code or not.

Comment: I get: `E5108: Error while calling lua chunk for luaeval(): [string "<VimL compiled string>"]:1: attempt to index global 'test' (a nil value)`

Comment: @BobbyWan-Kenobi Updated. My answer is still a bit incomplete... I'm looking at it from the Vim (not NeoVim) point of view... But hopefully this unblocks you?

Comment: Yes, no errors now. I should be able to reference that variable with `set statusline+=\ &Myvar` no?

Comment: I had to wrap it inside a function `fu! Hello()
  return luaeval('require("test").hello_string()')
endfu` I guess there's now way to directly reference variables in the status line?

Comment: @BobbyWan-Kenobi Syntax for statusline is `%{...}` with a Vim expression inside, so `set statusline=%{Myvar}`. Or `let &statusline = Myvar` to set statusline as a string...

Comment: With the second one `%{Hello()}` beware that the status line is evaluated very frequently, so the overhead of calling into Lua might become quite apparent...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Actually the idea is to write a Lua plugin to manage my status line. So the variable approach is better, right? Btw, I think the first error I got `E121: Undefined variable: v:lua`, was because the module was not *global or accessible from global tables*. But how can I make it accessible? (I can create another question for it)

Comment: @BobbyWan-Kenobi Yes, in general storing it into a variable and using that in statusline is better. You can use autocmd's (CursorHold, CursorMoved, CursorMovedI, etc.) to call into your Lua code and update the variable. There are some settings you can only access from statusline though (for example if you want to report the Vim mode you're in) so it might be hard to make it all in Lua *and* keep an acceptable performance.

Comment: I don't know why you're having the trouble with `v:lua`, but the E121 suggests `v:lua` itself is the problem... `v:lua` is a NeoVim thing (not in original Vim), so are you sure you're on NeoVim not Vim? Are you using a recent enough version of NeoVim? (Not sure when the feature was introduced... I'm more of a Vim user myself.) In any case, it seems to me that `v:lua` is mostly syntax improvement/syntax sugar on `luaeval()`, so you might want to stick with that and be compatible with Vim (and possibly older NeoVim too...)

Comment: When I open the `:help` I see *NVIM REFERENCE MANUAL* is there any command to check the version from inside the editor? From the command line I get **NVIM 0.4.3**. (Actually I chose Neovim for the "native" support for Lua, but from the docs I can see I have to write a considerable amount of boilerplate code(which I don't understand) to create a plugin.

Comment: I guess one thing is you can try `:help v:lua` to see if your documentation for NeoVim mentions it or not...

Comment: Damn: `E149: Sorry, no help for v:lua` ))

Comment: The `v:lua` interface was introduced in [PR #11338](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/11338) which has a milestone of 0.5, so looks like it's not generally available just yet... Stick to `luaeval()`!

Comment: Updated my answer to indicate that.